# DataTables.net how use multiple data source?

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I use the composant "http://datatables.net/".
With my datatables, I use ajax request to get the data from the serverSide. But I have an other datasource for one cell ("List Role") which use another ajax source.

How to use this sources for the cell("List Role") and how display a "`<selec...><option..>`" for the cell which is "ListRole"?

My code example:

```html
<table id="gridrole" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role Current</th>
            <th>List Role</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role Current</th>
            <th>List Role</th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
$('#gridrole').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Role/ReadRole/",
            "dataType": "json"
        },

        columns: [
            { "data": "UserName" },
            { "data": "Login" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "RoleName" },
            {
                "data": "ListRole"
            }

        ],

    });
```

Update

Example list role:

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"Admin"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Test"}]
```

Comment: How does the source for "ListRole" looks like? I get the feeling that ListRole also is included in the first data, and the other data source is a list of options?

Comment: @davidkonrad I had an example to listrole in my original post. The listRoles is not included in the first data. yes the other data is a list of options

Comment: My bad, totally overlooked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume other aspects of your dataTables initialisation are working well and the items of the first datasource looks something like

```
{
  "UserName": "test",
  "Login": "qwerty",
  "Email": "b@test.com",
  "RoleName": "Test",
  "ListRole": 2
 }
```

etc, and the listrole data source looks like

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"Admin"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Test"}]
```

etc. Then, I will suggest you read the listrole datasource only once, and create a jQuery object holding a `<select><option ..</select>` instance with the listrole `Id`'s and `Name`'s :

```
var $select = $('<select></select>');

$.getJSON('listrole.json', function(json) {
  for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
     $select.append('<option value="'+json[i].Id+'">'+json[i].Name+'</option>')
  }
});
```

and then in `columns` return a cloned `$select` (or actually its HTML) where the `<option>` that corresponds to the value of `ListRole` in the first datasource are selected :

```
columns: [
   ...
   { data: "ListRole",
     render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        var $clone = $select.clone();
        $clone.find('option[value="'+data+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        return $clone.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
      }
   }
]
```

have made a demo of the above -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/JW15Iblkz6rVSod3YWXw?p=preview**